# Firebase Storage hide data from the developer

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

Im doing a backup of the user data on Firebase Storage. I have set the private rules on the console using the auth.uid. Is there a way to hide the data on the console? I can currently browse all the users and its folders created on the console.

Comment: I believe [Frank's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50990960/6184356) applies to Firebase Console in general: there's no such feature at the moment.